Should I use both `main` and `exports` in a package.json?
The exports property (webpack docs, npm docs) of a package.json is relatively new feature, that allows to define multiple entry points for a package.
For example, we can provide a different entrypoint for require syntax vs import syntax, or we can allow imports like the-package/foo and the-package/bar.
Question is - given that my package has an exports property - is there any need to to have the main property? Perhaps for backwards compatibility for older tooling?
